# used if statement in select query does not work

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have an order list in csv file.  I want to transform the data.

here's my query. I have to add 2 new columns "gift box set" and blue oyser mushroom". If name in V column contains gift box set, then show 1, otherwise leave it blank.  Please help me to correct my query. also how can I give a new column name for those 2 added columns?

```
=query(orders!A2:AP134, "select Q, K, V, if(V="Gift Box Set              5lbs", "1", ""), if(V="Blue Oyster Mushroom   3lbs", "1", "")", true)
```

[image]

Comment: About column names. You can use [`LABEL` construction](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#label).

Answer (score 1):

There is no if statement in `QUERY` syntax.

Try a simpler approach without `QUERY`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  {
    Q2:Q134,
    K2:K134,
    V2:V134,
    IF(V2:V134 = "Gift Box Set              5lbs", 1, ""),
    IF(V2:V134 = "Blue Oyster Mushroom   3lbs", 1, "")
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({Q2:Q, K2:K, 
 IF(V2:V="Gift Box Set              5lbs", "1", ), 
 IF(V2:V="Blue Oyster Mushroom   3lbs", "1", )})
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER({Q2:Q, K2:K, 
 IF(V2:V="Gift Box Set              5lbs", "1", ), 
 IF(V2:V="Blue Oyster Mushroom   3lbs", "1", )}, 
 REGEXMATCH(V2:V, "Gift Box Set              5lbs|Blue Oyster Mushroom   3lbs"))
```

or:

```
=QUERY(INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(V2:V, "Gift Box Set              5lbs|Blue Oyster Mushroom   3lbs"), 
 {Q2:Q, K2:K, ROW(A2:A)^0}, )), 
 "where Col3=1", 0)
```